# BizTalk flat file nested xml

Tags: xsd, schema, biztalk, biztalk-2010

BizTalk flat file schema with nested nodes is giving me some trouble.  What is happening is that the child record delimiter is showing up as data in the last field.  I followed the recipe from this old blog post.

[Managing Flat Files in BizTalk 2004](http://geekswithblogs.net/synBoogaloo/archive/2005/04/22/37294.aspx)

Here is the input and schema are here.

https://bitbucket.org/kirk98445/stuff/src/90becbaa638b1bc42555cf84f2a1a4cb4f3cd3fc?at=master

Result is that the xml looks fine for the most part except for the crlf in the user and ponumber fields.

```
<Orders xmlns="http://KS.Biztalk.EDI.Common.Amtech.ASN.FlatFileSchema1"><Header><user>USER_1234
</user></Header><Order><OrderHeader><ponumber>PO_001
</ponumber></OrderHeader><LineItems><LineItem><item>Item32  33</item></LineItem><LineItem><item>Item63  45</item></LineItem></LineItems></Order><Order><OrderHeader><ponumber>PO_002
</ponumber></OrderHeader><LineItems><LineItem><item>Item454 12</item></LineItem></LineItems></Order></Orders>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues with your schema.
Record "Orders" - The Child Delimiter Type property is not set for a delimited record.
Record "Order" - The Child Delimiter Type property is not set for a delimited record.

Usually with this sort of flat file I would create one schema for the header, and then one for the Order & Order Lines. Then in the flat file dissembler define set the Header schema and the Document schema to the above two. 
This way it will de-batch you will get a message for each purchase order in the file.

But if you want it in a single schema, try this schema that uses a Sequence Group node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://KS.Biztalk.EDI.Common.Amtech.ASN.FlatFileSchema1" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://KS.Biztalk.EDI.Common.Amtech.ASN.FlatFileSchema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Orders" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="true" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" child_delimiter_type="hex" default_child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" default_child_order="postfix" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Orders">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Header">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="HEADER" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x09" child_order="prefix" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="user" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:groupInfo sequence_number="2" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:element name="OrderHeader">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="PURCHASE" child_order="prefix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x09" sequence_number="1" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="ponumber" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="LineItem">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="LINEITEM" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x09" child_order="prefix" sequence_number="2" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="item" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Qty" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="2" justification="left" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```